# PySimpleGUI : Update Window Property

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I would like to update the property `no_titlebar` of a PySimpleGUI Window.

What I want is that, **when we click a button**, the window which was **initially having titlebar should be having no titlebar**.

Is there any way to Implement this ?

```
from PySimpleGUI import *
lt=[[Button("No Layout")]]
wn=Window("Test",lt,no_titlebar=False)
while True:
    e,v=wn.read()
    if e=="No Layout":
        wn.Update(no_titlebar=True)
    else:
        break
```

I tried this but was getting an AttributeError

```
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'Update'
```

Comment: Yes, you got the answer `'Window' object has no attribute 'Update'`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no method `Update` for `sg.Window`, and no method to update `no_titlebar`.

Following code just for your reference, I know nothing about Linux, so you may need  to find the answer by youself about what value for `window.TKroot.wm_attributes("-type", value)` to restore toolbar.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def titlebar(state):
    try:
        if sg.running_linux():
            if state:
                window.TKroot.wm_attributes("-type", 'normal')  # Don't know what the option `normal` should be ...
            else:
                window.TKroot.wm_attributes("-type", 'dock')
        else:
            if state:
                window.TKroot.wm_overrideredirect(False)
            else:
                window.TKroot.wm_overrideredirect(True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'** Problem setting no titlebar {e} **')

layout = [
    [sg.Button("Title bar On/Off"), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window("Test", layout)
state = True
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == "Title bar On/Off":
        state = not state
        titlebar(state)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling. Python is case-sensitive.
'Window' object has an attribute 'update' and
'Window' object has no attribute 'Update'

Comment: It's not the spelling issue, the instance of the class `Window` don't have an attribute or method named `update` or `Update`.